# Importance of WHERE in LEFT join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty new to StackOverflow and never really needed to post but after some hours of reasearch I had to ask.
I could maybe change the DB, but I'm trying to find a solution here.

So I have 2 Tables in my DB, `[Pracas] and [Motoristas_Praca]`

The View is not returning anything when [Motoristas_Praca] is empty, because of the //Motoristas_Praca.PracaID=Pracas.PracaID

Here is my View

```
SELECT Pracas.Zona, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Motoristas_Praca.PracaID=Pracas.PracaID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Ocupantes' 
FROM Motoristas_Praca, Pracas GROUP BY Pracas.Zona
```

The [Pracas] has 2 entries

I want the View to return,

```
Zona          Ocupantes 
--------     -------------
string1        0

string2        0
```

...when [Motoristas_Praca] is empty

Sorry for the bad post, but I need your help :)

Comment: You might also take a look at this article since you are using the old style joins. The "newer" syntax has been around for almost 30 years now. :) https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`, to get the desired output.

```
SELECT Pracas.Zona,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Motoristas_Praca.PracaID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'Ocupantes' 
FROM Pracas
LEFT JOIN Motoristas_Praca ON Motoristas_Praca.PracaID=Pracas.PracaID
GROUP BY Pracas.Zona
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow